# The compiler option dagger.hilt.android.internal.projectType is not a recognized Hilt option. Is there a typo?

Tags: android, gradle, dagger-hilt

Im making an app with viewmodel, repository, room db, retrofit api and i tried to implement dependency injection with dagger hilt. Im not sure what causes the error, is it the dependencies or is it my app?

AppModule Dagger hilt :

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ViewModelComponent::class)
object AppModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideRetrofitApi(): ApiService {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://api.mangaupdates.com/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
            .create(ApiService::class.java)
    }
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideRepository(database: WebtoonApiDatabase, retrofit: ApiService): WebtoonRepository {
        return WebtoonRepository(database, retrofit)
    }
}
```

Fragment with view model :

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class ApiSectionFragment : Fragment() {
    private val viewModel: WebtoonApiViewModel by activityViewModels {
        val database = (activity?.application as WebtoonApplication).apiDatabase
        WebtoonApiViewModelFactory(provideRepository(database, provideRetrofitApi()))
    }
}
```

View model:

```
@HiltViewModel
class WebtoonApiViewModel @Inject constructor(private val repository: WebtoonRepository) : ViewModel()
```

Repository:

```
class WebtoonRepository @Inject constructor(database: WebtoonApiDatabase, private val retrofit: ApiService)
```

Application :

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class WebtoonApplication: Application() {
    val apiDatabase: WebtoonApiDatabase by lazy {
        WebtoonApiDatabase.getDatabase(this)
    }
}
```

build.gradle(module:app)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}
dependencies {
    //Dagger + Hilt
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.40.5"
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.42'
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.40.5"
    implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha03"
    kapt "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0"
}
```

build.gradle(project) :

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.0' apply false
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs' version '2.4.1' apply false
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android' version '2.45' apply fals
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt" version "1.2.40" apply false
}
```